# How to emit and event within a promise in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I'm seeing the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined` while trying to emit an event from child to parent component within a promise in `vuejs`. How best can I fix it?

```
<script>
    axios.patch('/api/travel_requests/cancel/'+travel_no)
              .then(function (response) {
                    this.$emit('something', 'done') // this line throws an error but works outside of this promise
                    console.log('parent component has listened')
               })
              .catch(function (error) {
                 console.log(error)
             })
    </script>
```

Comment: if you don't get it in the duplicate question you could do `then((response)=> {`

Comment: I didn't ask how to render input fields in `vuejs`, how is it a duplicate question?

Comment: Yes the question is not asked in the same way or with same title but the issue is the same and you could solve it with the same way using arrow function `.then((response)=>{this.$emit('something', 'done')`